# "Could not find bolts-tasks" error after upgrading Parse Android SDK from 3.0 to 4.2

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I'm trying to upgrade an existing project from Parse Android SDK from 3.0 to 4.2. I have the below dependencies in my app's build.gradle an in another module's build.gralde file called `foundation`:

```
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:4.2.0"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:ktx:4.2.0"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:coroutines:4.2.0"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:facebook:4.2.0"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:4.2.0"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.ParseUI-Android:widget:0.0.6"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.ParseUI-Android:login:0.0.6"
```

But now I'm getting the below error:

```
Could not find com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:4.2.0.
Required by:
    project :foundation
    project :foundation > com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:4.2.0
```

I'm guessing bolt-tasks 4.2.0 doesn't exist and somehow it's coming from the parse sdk. I tried cleaning and invalidating caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same, seems like an issue with 4.2.0 - downgrading to 4.1.0 works for now

Comment: adding a link to the github issue for resolution tracking in the future: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/1189

Comment: `Failed to resolve: com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:4.1.0` No matter what version it doesn't work for me.

Comment: the solution was posted in the tracking link above  - i'll copy it here for the future:

`so the official Parse documents are wildly out of date. Had to add maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' } to the settings.gradle file, and now it gets recognized. Parse docs show a setup with a pre Android Studio BumbleBee version.`

Comment: sorry for not updating my comment. As you can see, I found the issue and corrected the documentation. Hopefully, all is well on your end now as well.